# C# - Configuring attempts for job Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, limit, hangfire

I want to limit attempts for concrete job, does this attribute work like this? Or it sets attempts for all job for this method?

```
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
public void BackgroundMethod()
{
}
```

Tried to limit attemps for job

Answer (score 0):

[AutomaticRetry](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/dealing-with-exceptions.html) controls how many times Hangfire will retry the enqueued job if an exception is thrown inside.

If you want to limit how many times a function is called (per minute or so),  I've had success with the [Polly rate limiter](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/docs/strategies/rate-limiter.md). You can also pay for Hangfire Pro to get [throttling](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/throttling.html).